# Read many files in parallel with a specific sample rate

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I have 10 CSV files with million records. I want to read the 10 files in parallel, but with a specific rate (10 records per 5 sec). What is the efficient way to do so ?. I am using Windows in case someone will suggest to use OS scheduler

Comment: It might just be me, but I'm not sure what your end goal is here.  It sounds like you are trying to combine two tasks that aren't supposed to be combined

Comment: I want to simulate data streams. All the data I have are in many files. so I need to do same processes for all files in parallel and these files represent different types of data. For example, I have 10 types of data A, B, C,.. in file1, file2, file3,...I want to read 10 records from data of type A every 5 second from file 1 and the same for other files.

Comment: If it's about data stream, I would suggest having some other (Python?) program simply write 10 records/5 sec. Each program could write to a different file descriptor (if Windows supports that), or create TCP connections at different ports for each each program, to listen to and read the data streams from.

Answer (score 2):

I would try joblib
Here's some untested example code...

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import time

#make a function that takes ONE filename and processes it the way you want
def process_csv(filename):
    count = 0
    #open file using method of choice plain file or csv
    f = open(filename)
    for line in f: 
        #do we ignore header?
        if count == 0:
            count += 1  
            continue
        arr = line.strip().split(',')#use csv module if not simple text
        #do something, store it, whatever

        if count % 10 == 0:
            time.sleep(5)

    return 1


if __name__ == '__main__': #windows-only protection

    filenames = ['file1', 'file2', ..., 'file10']

    dummy = Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(process_csv)(fn) for fn in filenames)
```

now, watch out if somebody is adding to those files as you are reading them...this code probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open 10 files.
2. Read 1 record from each file (or 10, the question is not clear).
3. Use these records.
4. Wait until the current 5 second interval elapses.
5. Go to 2.